# "Properties" versus "settings"

Tags: word-choice, nouns

When speaking about e.g. computer "objects" (files, documents or other things manipulable through a graphical user interface) what would you say is the difference between the object's **properties** and its **settings** - if the properties (as well as the settings) can be edited/changed?

**EDIT:** I should clarify that I refer to the presentation in a user interface (from a user perspective) - not in relation to programmers/programming languages.

Comment: Are you asking in terms of what these words would mean to a programmer/computer scientist, or to a normal computer user?

Comment: It all boils down that we need details about which meaning is meant. Personally I thought the question is about "properties" as in "right-click the file and select 'properties' to bring up the dialog".

Comment: @Joe Blow, I'll admit that the choice of "object" perhaps is a bit unwise, since it has a certain meaning to programmers. If you find it shambolic(?) I have tried to clarify, but please let me know, if it isn't clear enough, still. After all, from my understanding, this forum is about clear and "correct" communication :)

Comment: @agib, Well done on clearing up the question.  I truly apologise if I appeared aggressive.  I am only 5'1" and 89 years old so you can be sure I am not aggressive!  Might I suggest very simply editing the initial paragraph to "computer interfaces"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of this is in the context of computer user interfaces, I can't really comment on the more general meaning.

Properties are attributes of a thing that are somehow inherent to it. Examples of properties are:

- the amount of memory in your computer
- the type of processor/CPU in your computer
- the size of a hard disk in your computer
- the size of a given file

You can't usually change properties directly. You can open the computer and add more memory, but you can't just pull a "memory" slider to the right to add more memory.

Settings are attributes that *can* easily be modified. Examples of settings are:

- the background color and/or image of your desktop
- the format used to display the time of day
- the location where your browser stores downloaded files

Note that there is a *separate* meaning of this in the world of [object-oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) (a part of software development) where a property is *any* attribute of an object, no matter if it's changeable or not. But even here the terminology can vary a lot between languages.

Comment: Your answer actually would generalise to the real world quite well. Consider a house. A property of it is the number of bedrooms. A setting would be the temperature of the central heating.

Comment: @Vincent: Indeed, the concept is similar enough. I simply don't haven't heard those terms used with those meanings before. So I can't judge if they are actually used this way outside of computer user interfaces.

Comment: Unfortunately, while the distinctions given here are true of "real world" objects, they aren't true of the *metaphorical* objects in the world of software. In the programming world, an *object* is a specific instance of a *class* (a definition that can describe any of a number of similar things). For instance, I can create a class named *Person* that I can use in my program to represent the qualities or aspect of a "real" person sufficient for my program.

Comment: To represent an individual in my program, I create an *instance* of that class. That *instance* is an *object*, and I can set (and later interrogate or change) the *properties* of that object: name, age, sex, income, job title, and so forth. *That's* what a "computer object" is. As far as *settings* goes, the ordinary meaning in computerdom is the same as it is in unwarped world of real people.

Comment: Wel that's what an "object" is in the discourse of OO programming, or computer science generally.  I've never, ever heard the term "computer object."  "computer object" just sounds ... bizarre and meaningless!

Comment: @Joachim - The words are used just like this in philosophy and biology. I'm not so sure about mortals... I may try it out on some unsuspecting English speakers sometime.

Comment: @Stan: I'm well aware of this, which is why I specifically mentioned software **UI**. In software development the meaning is quite different.

Comment: @Joe Blow: the questions here are often posed by people who are not particularly conversant with English or with a specific subset of the language. The phrase "computer 'object'" is a way of adding context to the question, separating the term "object" from its everyday, physical, meaning. That the question refers to "objects" in the OOP sense of the term seems quite obvious to me.

Comment: @Stan: *if* the question is about the OOP sense, then it is not really a question about the english language and fits better on SO or programmers.SE.

Comment: @Joachim: you're probably right, if it's dealing with programming rather than the use of the language of programmers from an outsider's perspective. It's hard to live a life that doesn't run up against someone else's jargon once in a while.

Comment: @Stan Hi Stan -- it's possible the questioner was referring to OO when he used the word "objects." But I think not, I think the question was something to do with user preferences, and the OP threw in the word "object" because he/she had heard it somewhere in relation to computing and thought it was relevant here.  IMO an non-native-english computer programmer (I'm sure you work with them as much as me) would not be **quite** so muddled up - if you know about OIO you wouldn't ask such a question, it makes no sense. I agree w/ Joachim in his comments at top. Anyway, it's all highly irrelevant...

Comment: ... because the questioner is a one-hit disappering user who we'll never hear from again. But it does raise **an interesting issue**.  IMO, when a question is an utter shambles, it's not a good idea for people to jump in and supply "answers" (even if the information in itself, such as presented here, is useful and correct, in and of itself).  The only real response to a "question" like the above, is "Hmm, let's step back, so far all we have is a total muddle - tell us more, Mr OP."  You know what I mean?  We collectively serve nothing by "answering" confused shambleses. @stan

Comment: @Stan also purely FWIW, I think you're (sensibly) forgetting that "Windows" (shudder) uses the word "properties" I believe as part of the user experience, in relation to preferences - I think.  (A couple of others mentioned this.)  Anyway again the only thing proved here, as an astounding amount of time can be wasted by many people, on shambolic questions.

Comment: Why so aggressive @Joe Blow ??? Yes, it's my first time here on English SE, but I'm quite active on UX SE. I was thinking that a language question would be more suitable here than on UX SE, but perhaps that was a wrong assumption... Instead of talking about muddle/shambolic question, a more constructive stance would be to, gently, ask: Please tell us more. And then, if the question is judged not to be relevant here, point to a better way of/resource for answering the question.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Joachim Sauer, I think your distinction is quite useful, although the size of e.g. a file can be altered by editing the contents. But that's why you stress that settings generally are easier to change than properties.

Comment: @agibsen: but that's just the difference: the size of a file can be modified *by editing the contents*. I.e. modifying the size is an indirect result of some other action.

Answer (score 4):

Every software developer will say, that "computer" object has neither *properties* (except for some software languages, where *property* is a method with special syntax) nor *settings*.

*Settings* is more of a set of external data, that specifies the behaviour of computer entity - application as a whole or some submodule in it. In UI they are frequently refered as *options* or *preferences*.

*Properties* (if we are not talking about special syntax I mentioned earlier) - I can't say I hear this word applied to computer entities often. I'd say it can be applied to a special kind of settings, that are stored in external files on disk (called *property files* or *configuration files*).

Comment: *Every* software developer? Not this one -- ever.

Comment: @Stan Rogers I feel for you.

Comment: A "property" is *never* a method, although its accessors and mutators (its getters and setters) might be. Even if the property is entirely virtual (that is, if it is entirely an artifact of its accessor and is unsettable), the property and its accessor are *not* the same thing. The property, in that case, is the value *returned by* the accessor, not the accessor itself. It has always been thus.

Comment: @Stan Rogers I didn't want to start an argument about names, but since you insist... You're talking about *fields* of an object, not [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx#). And yes, they are not methods.

Comment: Fields are merely the storage entities, not the properties themselves. They may or may not be accessible as properties (and the "data hiding" dictum suggests that they never be accessible except through accessors and mutators), and the value returned by the accessor or set by the mutator may or may not be the same as the value stored in the field. (I've been in the game for more than thirty years; you can keep going if you want, but you'd better know what you're talking about.)

Answer (score 2):

When talking about objects (instances of classes in an object-oriented language) you should use the word *properties*.

*Settings* apply more properly to applications and environments; they are changes in configuration. A *setting* may be controlled entirely by a single property of a single object in some cases, but the object itself doesn't have a *setting*, it has a *property*.

(There is a little room for confusion here, since the act of changing a property is often accomplished using a *method* called a *setter*, and in many languages the setter is named by convention *setPropertyName()*. And it doesn't help at all that Java uses *.properties as the default name for an application's configuration file.)

Comment: Should we now **delete all the answers and comments** which relate to OO programming, which we now know is utterly irrelevant?